# Mongoose ODM: how to get first one and last five elements from array of embedded documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, slice

I'm writing a simple forum engine with NodeJS/Express/MongoDB and I have a little problem with Mongoose ODM for Mongo.

I have board, thread and post models like those (a little bit simplified):

```
var boardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
});


var threadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    board: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Board', index: true},
    posts: [postSchema],
});


var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    thread: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Thread'},
});
```

So posts are embedded in thread documents. I want to display a list of threads with some posts: the **first one AND five latest** ones. Is it possible to achieve that in one query? I can get first **OR** latest five using the **slice** function, but I want something more elegant than two almost identical queries. Here is my current query:

```
threadModel
    .find(
        {board: boardId, is_deleted: false}, 
        {posts: {$slice: -5}}
    )
    .sort({last_updated: 1, is_sticky: 1})
    .skip(settings.threadsOnPage * parseInt(pagePointer, 10))
    .limit(settings.threadsOnPage)
    .populate('board')
    .exec(function(err, threads){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (threads === []) return callback(404);
        callback(null, threads);
    });
```

Comment: Since you always want the first post have you considered denormalizing it out of the array and storing it in its own field?  It'll always exist and you treat it "specially" so it's a good candidate for it.

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution. I'm new to NoSQL databases, so I still try to avoid duplicating things, and maybe that's not the way things work there.

Actually, yesterday I have tried to populate a field in the thread model, but couldn't get it working - that field always had null value.